# Custom django auth backend not logging the user with base login view

Tags: python, django, authentication, custom-authentication

I am writing a custom django auth backend that sends a post request with just the username and password info to a server, the server replying with some data about the user if the login/password couple is correct (403 response otherwise)

The code works fine, create the user if it doesn't already exists, then returns the user (made unit tests that are passing). However, the default login view doesn't log the user in.
Here's the code for the backend :

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
import requests

User = get_user_model()


class CustomAuthBackend():
    def authenticate(self, username, password):
        response = requests.post(
            LOGIN_SERVER_URL,
            data={'username': username, 'password': password}
        )
        if response.status_code == 200:
            try:
                return User.objects.get(username=username)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                user = User.objects.create_user(
                    username=username,
                    password=password
                )
                user_data = response.json()['user']
                user.last_name = user_data['last_name']
                user.first_name = user_data['first_name']
                user.email = user_data['email']
                user.save()
                return user

    def get_user(self, username):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

And the call for the login view (the custom form is just to have placeholders on the form):

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.views import logout, login
from accounts.forms import CustomAuthenticationForm

url(
        r'^login$',
        login,
        {
            'template_name': 'login.html',
            'authentication_form': CustomAuthenticationForm
        },
        name='login'
    ),
```

I have spent a fair amount of time tracking down why the user isn't logged in, without any success.
Is there anyone to enlighten me on this issue ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend), the `get_user` method should take the primary key of the model as the argument:

```
def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

Comment: That did the trick, I forgot that the username in the django user model wasn't the primary key. Many thanks !